# Session Changed In Webhook

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, stripe-payments, webhooks

Im building a webshop using Stripe and .Net, and I'm having some problems with the session not persisting in my webhook and as a result the webhook is unable to get cart or customer information.

My add to cart method looks like this:

```
            var cartList = new List<CartProduct>();

            var stringObj = _session.GetString("cart");

            /* Logic for deserializing stringObj into List<CartProduct> */

            stringObj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cartList);

            _session.SetString("cart", stringObj);
```

If I look at _session I can see it has an ID. However, when I try to get the cart from my webhook, the session ID has changed and as a result the cart is null.

My get cart method fires at charge.succeeded using the webhook and starts of like this:

```
            var cart = _session.GetString("cart"); // Returns null because session has changed

            var cartList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CartProduct>>(cart); // Exception thrown due to cart being null
```

I've tried making the cookie essential, and setting CheckConsentNeeded to false. This is my ConfigureServices method of the startup.cs file:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
            services.AddSession(options => { 
                options.Cookie.Name = "cart";
                options.Cookie.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(365);
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true; // make the session cookie Essential
            });
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["DefaultConnection"], b => b.MigrationsAssembly("ShopTutorial.Database")));

            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });
        }
```

app.UseSession(); has been added to the Configure method of the same class.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that Stripe Checkout is a redirect to Stripe's site, and then another redirect back to your site. Some of the answers listed in these search results will likely be helpful for how to re-establish the session after the redirects: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=.net+session+after+redirect

Comment: /How are you running this? In Visual Studio or are you hosted somewhere

Comment: Thanks! Yes I'm using VS 2019 for this. From what I've gathered a distributed cache could perhaps be used to store the session in a db. The distributed cache could then be injected into the webhook and the session pulled from the db. Could that be a viable option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding the cart information to a MemoryCache lasting for 60 seconds 
with the Stripe payment intent description (a new GUID) as a key:

```
        var intent = new CreatePaymentIntent();

        ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;

        cache.AddOrGetExisting(intent.Description, Cart, new CacheItemPolicy {
            AbsoluteExpiration =
                DateTimeOffset.Now.AddSeconds(60.0)
        });
```

Then, in the webhook I called the same cache with the specific key that is stored in the intent object's description sent back from Stripe:

```
        var charge = stripeEvent.Data.Object as Stripe.Charge;

        ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;

        var cart = (Cart)cache.Get(charge.Description);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to solve this in PHP and what I figured out so far is, you have to save your cart/order/customer to the database and put the relevant ids to payment intent as metadata. So that later in the webhook, it can be extracted from the payment intent.

In .NET it would be something like this:

```
var options = new PaymentIntentCreateOptions
{
    Amount = 1099,
    Currency = "cad",
    // Verify your integration in this guide by including this parameter
    Metadata = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
      { "integration_check", "accept_a_payment" },
      { "cart_id", 10022 },
    },
};
```

Comment: That could be a solution as well. Thanks!